# SQL - Fetch associated data from multiple table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 4 tables. The table does not contain any `foreign key` reference

t1:

```
| id  | name           |
+-----+----------------+
| a1  | cheese         |
| a2  | butter         |
| a3  | milk           |
```

t2:

```
| id  | name        |   t1_id      |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| b1  | item1       | a1           |
| b2  | item2       | a2           |
| b3  | item3       | a3           |
```

t3:

```
| id  | name        |   t2_id      |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| c1  | item4       | b1           |
| c2  | item5       | b2           |
| c3  | item6       | b3           |
```

t4:

```
| id  | name        |   t3_id      |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| d1  | item7       | c2           |
| d2  | item8       | c3           |
```

I need to get all associated data.

When I specify 'a1' I expect something as,

```
| name     | name        |   name       |   name       |
+----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| cheese   | item1       |item4         |              |
```

I used the following query,

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name FROM t1 AS a 
INNER JOIN t2 AS b ON b.id = c.id 
INNER JOIN t3 AS c ON c.id = b.id 
INNER JOIN t4 AS d ON d.id = c.id;
```

This fetches no result as `INNER JOIN t4 AS d ON d.id = c.id` does not have matching value.

How to return the intermediate result? Is this query optimized (or) should I write separate queries to fetch this? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want `left join`s?

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name
FROM t1 AS a LEFT JOIN
     t2 AS b
     ON b.id = c.id LEFT JOIN
     t3 AS c
     ON c.id = b.id LEFT JOIN
     t4 AS d
     ON d.id = c.id;
```

Comment: Using LEFT JOIN gives multiple results. Is this the expected behavior? I expect single row in Resultset